# How to save each array values in next line?

Tags: 7, theming, updating, caching

I am having a requirement that, automating the contributed module configurations via hook_update. I have a text area, where i need to mention different URLs with one  URL/line. For reference look into the image:

[image]

To achieve this I have to use `variable_set();` function. 
I tried something like below but not able to get all the values displayed.

```
$test = array('abc/*','xyz/*','ijk/*');
variable_set('boost_testing', $test);
```

This code is setting only first row, it will not come to next row.

So please suggest something I can do by using `<br>` or `\n` so that i can display each values next row. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass paths as a string instead of array:

```
$test = "abc/*\nxyz/*\nijk/*\n";
variable_set('boost_testing', $test);
```

Remember to use double quotes for the $test string.